# What are the different types of Divine love mentioned in the Narada Bhakti Sutras?

Tags: bhakti, narada, love, narada-bhakti-sutra

Narada Bhakti Sutras or aphorisms of love was a text written by Narada Muni. In this, he talks about the various attributes of Bhakti or Divine love. What are the different types of Bhakti as mentioned in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference to different types of Bhakti or Divine love is found the Shloka 82 of the Narada Bhakti Sutra.

Shloka

> |Gunmahatmyasakti roopasakti poojasakti smaranasakti dasyasakti |
>
> || Sakhyasakti vatsalyasakti kantasakti atmanivedanasakti ||
>
> || tanmayatasakti paramavirhasakti rupa ekadha api ekadashadha bhavati ||

Translation

> …Though it is only one, there are eleven flavours of Love:
>
> **Gunmahatmyasakti** - adoring the qualities
>
> **Roopasakti** - adoring the form
>
> **Poojasakti** - worship
>
> **Smaranasakti** - constant rememberance of the Divine
>
> **Dasyasakti** - wanting to serve the God
>
> **Sakhyasakti** - companionship, taking God as one’s beloved
>
> **Vatsalyasakti** - considering God as one’s child
>
> **Kantasakti** - considering God as one’s own partner. As centre of attraction of all sorts in life.
>
> **Atmanivedanasakti** - Offering every moment, this entire body, mind - physical, mental emotional; entire life, total letting go.
>
> **Tanmayatasakti** - Being immersed in knowledge that he is already in you and every part is immersed in Him.
>
> **Paramavirhasakti** - longing, excruciating longing

Referenced from [this](http://www.artoflivinguniverse.org/2012/11/narad-bhakti-sutras-sutra-82-a.html) commentary on the Narada Bhakti Sutras.