# Charity to someone married girl after puberty

Tags: mahabharata, charity

Rishi [Markandeya says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03199.htm) below when listing 16 types of futile charities:

> **The gift to one that has married a girl after the accession of puberty, to females,** to one that sports with snakes, and to one that is employed in menial offices, is also in vain.

The highlighted part is saying if one marries a girl after she reaches puberty, that man becomes ineligible from receiving charity? Are there any other scriptures which support this?

Charity to females also is strange one.

Or, these are another translation issues?

Comment: In olden days, child marriage was the norm. Even today there is a prayaschitta prescribed for marrying a girl post puberty. But people today think that child marriage meant child sexual relations (pedophilia) - they're incorrect. There was no sex until at least after menses (usually a few years after menses). They also think the grrom would 30 and the bride 13 - again not the case in practice. Both would be under 15. You can read spiritual reasons behind it [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/what-was-the-true-reason-behind-the-practice-of-child-marriage/18602#18602)

Comment: *"Charity to females also is strange one."* - One predominant characteristic of Kali Yug is the subservience of men to women. The feminist movement, financial independence, divorce rates - are symptoms of this (and coming) eras. And there is nothing morally wrong with it - if women want to live independent lives, none can argue against what an individual Jiva/Atma wants to do. That is their choice. This choice also has repercussions -  If they want a family life, the old proverb 'No 2 lions in a forest' will apply.

Comment: @ram, thanks, but in Mahabharata itself there are references where it says the father started thinking about marriage when daughter reaches puberty. Draupadi was born adult; so was not married as a child. Swayamvaras were in practice; can't be expecting a 8 year old to choose her husband?

Comment: yeah. where's the contradiction ? not everybody followed the rules. that's why the specific injunction (do not donate to someone who didn't follow this rule) exists. a girl is allowed to choose her own husband if her father doesn't marry her off by waiting 3 years post puberty i.e around 16.