# Is notion of Pati - Parameśvara (husband is the Supreme Lord) based on scriptures?

Tags: scripture, women, marriage, men

In this question: [Why a husband is called पतीपरमेश्वर (Pati Parmeshwar)? Whom should a wife devote to at time of death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/why-a-husband-is-called-%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%a4%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%b6%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b5%e0%a4%b0-pati-parmeshwar-whom-should-a-wife-devote?r=SearchResults), one of the answer gives reasons why husband might be considered like the Lord, by citing a conversation between devī Kauśalyā & Mātā Sītā, before the three, leave for the vanavāsa.

However the above QnA just gives one possibility.
I'm looking for a more comprehensive answer from multiple scriptural perspective.

---

#### Question:

Is notion of Pati - Parameśvara ( पति परमेश्वर ), i.e., for a wife her husband is the only Supreme Lord, based on, and explicitly stated in the Scripture(s)?

Please include multiple references from different scriptures on the same.

Answer (score 7):

In Atri Smriti (aka Atri Samhita) we find the following verse:

> A woman, desirous of bathing in a sacred water, should drink the water
> washing the feet of her husband, of S'iva or of Vishnu. She should,
> thereby, attain to the most excellent station. (137)

It implies that for a married woman, her husband is equal to Shiva/Vishnu (or Parameswara).

Similarly, Manu Smriti says:

> 2.67. The nuptial ceremony is stated to be the Vedic sacrament for women (and to be equal to the initiation),
> **serving the husband (equivalent to) the residence in (the house of the) teacher**, and the household duties (the same) as the (daily)
> worship of the sacred fire.

Original verse has "patiseva guru-vaso" which basically means that for the woman her husband is like what the Guru is to his disciple. And, in Hinduism the Guru is well-known to be treated as Parabrahman, as we can see from the famous sloka "Gurur brahma, Gurur vishnu, Gurur devoh maheswarah .."

Comment: You should add the Sanskrit verses in this specific case. It'll be more appreciated.

Comment: @Vivikta I am quoting from a PDF that has Atri Smriti only in English. So I need to search for the Sanskrit verse. For the Manu Smriti verse, the Sanskrit sloka can be found from here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145659.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most definitely. Here I am quoting examples from 2 Puranas -

> *[Shiv Puran 2.3.54](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226118.html)* - She who serves her husband with love and considers him her **sole lord**, enjoys all pleasures here and obtains salvation hereafter along with her husband .............. Even when beaten by him she shall remain glad and say **“I may even be killed, O lord”** .............. O Goddess, the husband is **superior tO Brahmā, Viṣṇu or Śiva**, for a chaste lady her husband is on a par with Śiva .............. If she furiously retorts to her husband she is **born as a  bitch** in a village or as a vixen in a secluded place .............. To a wife the **husband is god, preceptor, virtue, holy centre and sacred rite.** She should cast off everything and adore him **alone**

> *[Skand Puran 3.2.7](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423628.html)* - Even when dragged up by him, she does not cry aloud. Even if she is beaten by him, she continues to be gracious. When he says, “Do this”, she replies, “My lord, be assured that it is done” .............. after **meditating on her husband**, she should look at the sun .............. She should never transgress the words of her husband. This is - **the highest virtue and the holiest of worships.** .............. Desirous of taking holy dip in a sacred Tīrtha, she should drink the water with which her husband’s feet are washed. To a woman the husband is **superior to Lord Śaṅkara and Lord Viṣṇu** .............. A hot-tempered woman who, when addressed, gives rude reply, is reborn **as a BITCH** in a village or as a vixen in a desolate forest. This is - the greatest and **only sacred observance of women** that they should resolve to take their food only after worshipping the feet of their husbands ............... Husband is the LORD; husband is the PRECEPTOR. **He alone** is the veritable dharma sacred rite, holy shrine etc. Hence after setting aside everything, the wife should **worship solely her husband** .............. Viṣṇu-worship must be performed with the intellect directed towards the husband and **not otherwise.** She should always meditate upon her husband as having taken **the form of Viṣṇu, Hari.**

Comment: I can't believe this. WOW.

Comment: @Vivikta Thanks. I hope you will give me upvote instead of downvote this time haha :)

Comment: So which scripture lays down the rules of how women should be treated?

Comment: May i know why you capitalized certain phrases? Moreover your answer looks apt for question which asks, "what will happen if wife doesn't consider pati as Parameshwara"?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have capitalized the parts which show how divine the husband is for the wife and how he is supreme in the house.... I had answered question by Amethyst