# Why don't we refer Lord Shiva as pita (father) like we refer Goddess Kali as maa kali (mother)?

Tags: gods, goddess

We reffer Goddess Kali as maa (mother) Kali but we don't reffer God Shiva as pita(father) Shiva.
Not just that we reffer all female Goddess(Lakshmi,Durga, Parvati) as *Maa* but we don't do the same for the 3 main gods(Shiva, Vishnu and Brahmaa).

**What is the reason behind it**?

Comment: The word *pita* for several gods used is as *jagata-pita*, and equivalently for females *jagata-mãtã*. For the female energies, the use of the word mata **might** relate to the same very reasons as to why one cannot develop *madhurya-rasa bhakti bhava* towards any female divinity. Moreover, it can be more of a "popular" practice to call the female divinities as *maa*, rather than any particular religious injunctions. One can of course call any form of divinity as their mother - father (*mata- pita*), because they are the parents for whole creation itself.

Comment: @Vivikta "madhurya-rasa bhakti" what is the meaning of this.

Comment: [This](https://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=681) & [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/what-are-the-different-types-of-divine-love-mentioned-in-the-narada-bhakti-sutra) , please read these two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true that Lord Shiva isn't referred to as the father.

In Adi Shankara's [Annapurna Stotram](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/annapoorna/annapoorna_stotram.php) itself we find one such reference:

> क्षत्रत्राणकरी महाऽभयकरी माता कृपासागरी
>  साक्षान्मोक्षकरी सदा
> शिवकरी विश्वेश्वरश्रीधरी ।
>  दक्षाक्रन्दकरी निरामयकरी
> काशीपुराधीश्वरी
>  भिक्षां देहि कृपावलम्बनकरी मातान्नपूर्णेश्वरी ॥१०॥
>
> Kssatra-Traanna-Karii Mahaa-[A]bhaya-Karii Maataa Krpaa-Saagarii
> Saakssaan-Mokssa-Karii Sadaa Shiva-Karii Vishveshvara-Shrii-Dharii
> |
>  Dakssaa-Kranda-Karii Niraamaya-Karii
> Kaashii-Pura-Adhiishvarii
>  Bhikssaam Dehi Krpa-Avalambana-Karii
> Maata-Annapuurnne[a-Ii]shvarii ||10||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 10.1: (Salutations to Mother Annapoorna) Whose Great Power Protects the Devotees and grants them Great Fearlessness; Who is the Great
> Mother and an Ocean of Compassion,
> 10.2: Whose Divine Form is a Visible bestower of Liberation and Whose presence always brings Auspicious blessings; Who is indeed the
> repository of the Sri (Prosperity, Welfare and Auspiciousness) of
> Visweswara (Shiva),
> 10.3: Who makes Daksha (symbol of ego) Cry and in that repentence makes him Pure; Who is the Ruling Mother of the city of Kasi,
> 10.4: O Mother Annapoorneswari, Please grant us the Alms of Your Grace; Your Grace which Support all the Worlds.
>
> अन्नपूर्णे सदापूर्णे शङ्करप्राणवल्लभे ।
>  ज्ञानवैराग्यसिद्ध्यर्थं
> भिक्षां देहि च पार्वति ॥११॥
>
> Annapuurnne Sadaa-Puurnne Shangkara-Praanna-Vallabhe |
> Jnyaana-Vairaagya-Siddhy[i]-Artham Bhikssaam Dehi Ca Paarvati ||11||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 11.1: (Salutations to Mother Annapoorna) O Mother Annapoorna, You Who are always Full (with the gift of Food and Blessings), You Who are the
> Beloved of Shankara, ...
> 11.2: ... O Mother Parvati, Please grant me the Alms of Your Grace, to awaken within me Spiritual Knowledge and Freedom from all Worldly
> Desires.
>
> माता च पार्वती देवी पिता देवो महेश्वरः ।
>  बान्धवाः शिवभक्ताश्च
> स्वदेशो भुवनत्रयम् ॥१२॥
>
> **Maataa Ca Paarvatii Devii Pitaa Devo Maheshvarah** |
>  Baandhavaah Shiva-Bhaktaash-Ca Svadesho Bhuvana-Trayam ||12||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 12.1: **(Salutations to Mother Annapoorna) My Mother is Devi Parvati, and my Father is Deva Maheswara (Shiva)**,
> 12.2: My Friends are the devotees of Shiva, and my Country is all the Three Worlds (Whose Lord is Shiva-Parvati).

Comment: But commonly people don't say this. Why

Comment: In our place (Bengal) people address Lord Shiva as 'Baba" very often. And Baba in Bengali means father @DarkKnight

Comment: @DarkKnight Lord Shiva is fondly referred to as "Bhole Baba" by his devotees. And Baba means father. So it's not that uncommon too.

Comment: okay, thanks of this