# Why is the Madhurya Bhakti Bhāva (Kaanta Bhakti) considered the topmost or the best bhāva (sentiment), that a devotee can practice?

Tags: belief, worship, bhakti

As per [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/what-are-vatsalya-bhava-madhura-bhava-and-sakhya-bhava-described-in-the-scriptu) , the different kinds of *Bhakti-Bhāva / Rasa* (i.e., Mode/Types of Devotion), which includes: Mādhurya, Vātsalya, Sākhya, Santa, Dāsya., aren't to be found in any of the authoritative scriptures, but are the later views of eminent *āchāryas* of some relevant sampradāyas.

Further, [in this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2540/17833), the accepted answer **proclaims** that:

> > > .... There remains no personal desire but only the desire for the Lord's happiness. **Mādhurya Bhāva is the top most devotional sentiment which only a few, out of the many, practice properly.** And for those few, God is truly their everything;....

## So, **my question is:**

- ### Why is the Mādhurya Bhāva ( Sweetness/Love Sentiment ), is to be specifically eulogized as **the best or the highest or the pinnacle of devotion**, among all the known bhāvas ?

Because, as far as my limited knowledge goes, I'd like to believe that there can't be a sense of high/low or ranks/partisanship, in case of Bhakti (devotion), be it of any kind.

Since, The Supreme is said to be:

> Tvam-Eva Maataa Ca Pitaa Tvam-Eva। 
> Tvam-Eva Bandhush-Ca Sakhaa Tvam-Eva। 
> Tvam-Eva Viidyaa Dravinnam Tvam-Eva ।
> Tvam-Eva Sarvam Mama Deva Deva ॥
>
> > Meaning:
> > You Truly are my Mother And You  Truly are my Father.
> > You Truly are my Relative And You Truly are my Friend.
> > You Truly are my Knowledge and You Truly are my Wealth.
> > You Truly are my All, My God of Gods.

And, thus I'd believe that, comparing or ranking one kind of bhakti (mode of Devotion) with other kind, and thus, one kind of bhakta (devotee) with other kind of bhakta (devotee) , is both an insult to the devotee and thus the God itself.

Hence, for example: Categorizing Bhakti (devotion) into various classes or categories, will be like explicitly proclaiming, that, the Bhakti-Bhāva of Dhruva was better than that of Prahalada, or the Bhakti-Bhāva of *Rishi Mārkandeya* is lesser or not as much "good", as that of Lord Hanumāna. Or The elephant Gajendra's or Nārada Muni's devotion is not "topmost" or "not in its pinnacle", as compared to that of the Gopis.

Therefore, to mitigate the doubts, thus posed by me, I'd very much appreciate that the Answers to my question posed above, to **take into account these two perspectives while answering**:

1. The acceptability and viewpoints of various sampradāyas or schools on these explicit categorization of different types of Bhakti into ranks.
   i.e., How well is this concept of " types of 'Bhakti-Bhāva' " accepted/rejected and endorsed (and explained), by various Schools or sects within Hinduism?
2. The perspective and viewpoints of the original Sect(s) (or schools) which propounded or, accept this theory of "rank based categorization of devotion and devotees". i.e., How do they explain the doubts posed hereon by me ?