# example of bhakt relation/love to God/Goddess,where God/Goddess is the feminine beloved/premika

Tags: worship, goddess, love

1) humans(not avatara) like Meera, Andal etc viewed God **as husband/male beloved(premi)** and worshipped/loved Him as such.

2) as per this link https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/krishna-is-husband-of-everyone , krishna is **jagatpati and husband of everyone**(male or female)

3) Ramakrishna and countless others worshipped God in the form of **mother**.

**now, my question is that**:

a) whether there is any human(not avatara) , who worshipped/**loved God/Goddess as "feminine beloved"/"divine feminine beloved?**
ie, is there any example where "bhakt relationship to God/Goddess , where human bhakt(male/female) is premi and God/Goddess is feminine premikaa"

b) Is this bhav(emotion towards God/Goddess as premika) explicitly allowed/disallowed as per religious text?
If not allowed, then why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Madhurya bhava towards goddesses such as Radha, Parvati, etc.,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2517/3500)

Comment: Your second question is already asked and answered. See above comment. ^  Please remove that question and focus on the a single question. Read [ask] .

Comment: Sensations or emotions are not love. I guess you need to know what is love. Love is not possible with thoughts as thoughts are not love. love is found in the realm of thoughtlessness.

Comment: "Pati" does not mean Husband. "Pati" means "**LORD**" or "**Ruler**" , this is why Krishna is called JagatPati. Shiva-Parvati are together called "**Namo JagatPatibhyaam**"  in Uma Maheshvara Stuti, so does it mean "**Husbands of World**" or "**Ruler of World**"? Of course **RULER**. PM Modi is **RaashtraPati** so has he become "***Husband***" of all Indians, "**male or female**". NO

Comment: For Devi Paraambika Parvati Maheshaani Mahakali and her other forms, Shiva has Himself said That She is only Mother and only Mother. Brahma got in trouble when was enchanted by nrity of Mother Parvati. Kuvera who was actually a beautiful Deva, became "Kuvera"(ugly looking) , as he was fascinated at Mother Parameshvari.

Comment: it is allowed but it is a path fraught with many dangers. It is not encouraged as most who attempt it slip from it disastrously. It is much easier and safer to view the Lord as mother if one wants to worship the Divine as feminine..

Comment: “ Sensations or emotions are not love. I guess you need to know what is love. Love is not possible with thoughts as thoughts are not love. love is found in the realm of thoughtlessness” <—— I agree 

Comment: “ it is allowed but it is a path fraught with many dangers. It is not encouraged as most who attempt it slip from it disastrously. It is much easier and safer to view the Lord as mother if one wants to worship the Divine as feminine..” <—— A four years late question to ask, are there any known examples of religious devotees w/ this kind of madhurya bhav towards Devi ? I have wonder about this