# Madhurya Bhav Towards Goddess : Main Concern Would Be Romantic Feelings?

Tags: devi, bhakti

Reading through this thread and a couple others on here :

[Madhurya bhava towards goddesses such as Radha, Parvati, etc.,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/madhurya-bhava-towards-goddesses-such-as-radha-parvati-etc?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C45.9493)

So the main concern with the Goddess would be romantic and lustful type feelings towards them ?

MeeraBai is example of this kind of bhakti and I guess assumption is that her feeling towards Madhav wasn’t lustful in any way

But Meera (and Radha) saw Shyam in the role of like a husband, as their significant other.

If there was no romantic part to it, then wouldn’t it just be platonic and like a very good friend or really close mentor type thing ?

How is it categorized as madhurya bhav bhakti if the emotion is devoid of any romantic lustful type of feelings ?

Wondering someone can clarify this for me

Also wondering if there any examples of madhurya bhav bhakti towards the Goddess with any well known bhakts

Did any of the Shakta saints have madhurya bhav bhakti towards any form of Devi ? I know that the bhakti of BhamaKepa & RamaKrishna, Goddess was in the form of the Mother for them

Comment: Obviously Not . Vedas allow Polygyny but not Polyandry. And all godesses are already having a husband.

Comment: Downvotes  I didn’t mean to cause ire but I can see how a question like this might seem offensive. Prolly shouldn’t have posted it. Mods plz feel free to close or delete if that would best

Comment: Read about nigamananda paramhansa who had darshan of tara devi as his wife

Comment: Relax bro, read Philosophy well.